# How to write a query based on multiple tables?

Tags: django, python-2.7

I want the details of lender whose state,distrtict,religion,profession equals to borrowers details i.e;(state,distrtict,religion,profession)

This is borrowers models.py

```
class Borrower(models.Model):
    district = models.TextField(blank=True)
    state = models.TextField(blank=True)
    profession = models.TextField(blank=True)
    religion = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

This is Lenders models.py

```
class LenderStateDistrict(models.Model):
    lenderId = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50,**optional)
    district = models.CharField(max_length=50,**optional)

class LenderReligion(models.Model):
    lenderId = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    religion = models.CharField(max_length=50, **optional)

class LenderMultipleProfessions(models.Model):
    lenderId = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    profession = models.CharField(max_length=50,**optional)
```

views.py

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def xyz(request):
   borrower1= Borrower.objects.get(id =1)
   city = borrower1.district
   state = borrower1.state
   profession = borrower1.profession
   religion = borrower1.religion
```

I got every requirement for borrower and then how to query based on the three tables i.e; LenderStateDistrict,LenderReligion,LenderMultipleProfessions,if the borrowers district,state,religion,profession equals to the lenders then it should give the details how to query it?

Comment: what are you trying to retieve??

Comment: i want to retrive the lenderid

Comment: are these all your relevent models?

Comment: yes and is there any changes to do in these models?

Comment: thank you,i have done it

Answer (score 0):

There's a fundamental problem with your models. They are not related to each other. The power of Relational Database Management Systems lies in making relationships!

> Django offers ways to define the three most common types of database
>   relationships: many-to-one, many-to-many and one-to-one.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#relationships

At the very least you need to create a foreign key between your borrow and the lender. But it may need to be a ManyToMany relationship if users can borrows from more than one lender

Answer (score 0):

As @e4c5 mentioned that there is a problem with your models, try to relate your models with each other so that writing queries become easier.

Try to implement this way:

```
class District(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Religion(models.Model):
        field1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        field2 = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Profession(models.Model):
        field1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        field2 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

This should be your basic models according to your question, and then you can reference these models in your Lender and Borrower tables, this way:

```
class Lender(models.Model):
        district = models.ForeignKey(District, related_name="lender_district")
        profession = models.ForeignKey(Profession, related_name="lender_profession")
        religion = models.ForeignKey(Religion, related_name="lender_region")

class Borrower(models.Model):
        district = models.ForeignKey(District, related_name="borrower_district")
        profession = models.ForeignKey(Profession, related_name="borrower_profession")
        religion = models.ForeignKey(Religion, related_name="borrower_region")
```

This way you can achieve that query that you want. Suppose you want to access the details of Borrower and Lender who belongs to district where field1 = "xyz", for that you have to simply write:

```
lenders = Lender.objects.filter(district__field1="xyz")
borrowers = Borrower.objects.filter(district__field1="xyz")
```

And further simple way is:

```
district = District.objects.get(field1="xyz")  # get district
lenders = Lender.objects.filter(district=district)  # Get Lenders
borrowers = Borrower.objects.filter(district=district)  # Get Borrowers
```

You can implement ManyToMany relations too if lender and Borrower has more than one District, Religion or Profession.